# Sort data on Start time inside foreach Loop

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, foreach

I want to sort data on Start time inside foreach Loop.

Here is my Controller code:

```
private function getPatientList($search = null)
    {
        return Appointment::select('id', 'hospital_id', 'patient_id', 'serial_no', 'doctor_schedule_detail_id')
            ->whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->select('id', 'name', 'mobile_no', 'gender');
                if ($search) {
                    $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                        $q->where('name_hash', hash('sha256', $search))
                            ->orWhere('mobile_no_hash', hash('sha256', $search));
                    });
                }
            })->where('doctor_id', auth()->user()->doctor->id)
            ->where('hospital_id', auth()->user()->doctor->current_hospital_id)  
            ->where('status', '!=', 'Cancelled')
            ->whereDate('reporting_time', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('reporting_time')->get()
            ->groupBy('doctor_schedule_detail_id')->all();
    }
```

In model:

```
public function doctorScheduleDetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DoctorScheduleDetail::class);
    }
```

Appointment has doctor_schedule_detail_id col and relation with doctor_schedule_details table. In doctor_schedule_details table there is start_time column.

In my view:

```
@foreach ($appointments as $doctorScheduleId => $appointmentsGroup)
        
    <div class="row row-cards patient-list mb-3">
        <h4 class="mb-0"><span class="">Slot {{ $loop->iteration }}</span> [{{ date("g:i A",
            strtotime($appointmentsGroup[0]->doctorScheduleDetail->start_time)) }} - {{
            date("g:i A", strtotime($appointmentsGroup[0]->doctorScheduleDetail->end_time)) }}]</h4>
        @foreach ($appointmentsGroup as $appointment)
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">{{ $appointment?->patient?->name }}</div>
            --------
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here, I loop through a grouped data. I want to sort based on $appointmentsGroup[0]->doctorScheduleDetail->start_time - which is inside first foreach.

How can i do this?

I tried this but not working

```
private function getPatientList($search = null)
    {
        return Appointment::select('id', 'hospital_id', 'patient_id', 'serial_no', 'doctor_schedule_detail_id')
            ->whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->select('id', 'name', 'mobile_no', 'gender');
                if ($search) {
                    $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                        $q->where('name_hash', hash('sha256', $search))
                            ->orWhere('mobile_no_hash', hash('sha256', $search));
                    });
                }
            })->where('doctor_id', auth()->user()->doctor->id)
            ->where('hospital_id', auth()->user()->doctor->current_hospital_id)  
            ->where('status', '!=', 'Cancelled')
            ->whereDate('reporting_time', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('reporting_time')->get()
            ->groupBy('doctor_schedule_detail_id')
            ->map(function ($appointmentsGroup) {
                return $appointmentsGroup->sortBy(function ($appointment) {
                    return strtotime($appointment->doctorScheduleDetail->start_time);
                });
            })
            ->all();
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to sort by this value? what have you tried so far? there are methods for sorting collections... you also probably want to eager load this relationship

Comment: updated my post - added what i tried

Answer (score 1):

You have applied the sorting to the appointments within each group, rather than sorting the groups themselves.

so what you can do is, after grouping, sort the groups based on the start_time of the `doctorScheduleDetail` associated with the first appointment in each group.

Also Eager load the `doctorScheduleDetail`.

```
private function getPatientList($search = null)
{
    $appointments = Appointment::with('doctorScheduleDetail')
        ->select('id', 'hospital_id', 'patient_id', 'serial_no', 'doctor_schedule_detail_id')
        ->whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'mobile_no', 'gender');
            if ($search) {
                $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                    $q->where('name_hash', hash('sha256', $search))
                        ->orWhere('mobile_no_hash', hash('sha256', $search));
                });
            }
        })
        ->where('doctor_id', auth()->user()->doctor->id)
        ->where('hospital_id', auth()->user()->doctor->current_hospital_id)  
        ->where('status', '!=', 'Cancelled')
        ->whereDate('reporting_time', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->orderBy('reporting_time')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('doctor_schedule_detail_id');

    $sortedAppointments = $appointments->sortBy(function ($appointmentsGroup) {
        return $appointmentsGroup->first()->doctorScheduleDetail->start_time;
    });

    return $sortedAppointments->all();
}
```